# How to fix error with \maketitle during redefining of the list

Tags: errors, luatex, compiling, expl3

How  can I redefine list,avoiding of error with \maketitle. When I use `\maketitle` I get an error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\g__first_item_0_bool
```

Help me please. Why does it happen and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,interwordspace=true}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%command for labels
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g__aleksandr_labels_prop{descriptionlabel=1,labelenumi=0,labelenumii=0,labelenumiii=0,labelenumiv=0,labelitemi=0,lableitemii=0,labelitemiii=0,labelitemiv=0}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g__aleksandr_labels_prop{
\cs_set_eq:cc{orig@#1}{#1}
%set protected command depends of number of arguments,which you can see in \g__aleksandr_labels_prop. If we have one or more arguments,we check,if it an empty and if yes,we not tagging label.
\int_case:nnF{#2}{{0}{\cs_gset_protected:cpn { #1 }
     {
\tagstructbegin{tag=LI}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Lbl}
\tagmcbegin{tag=Lbl}
\use:c { orig@#1 }
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}}}
{\cs_gset_protected:cpn { #1 }##1
     {
\tagstructbegin{tag=LI}
%Why in enumerate not increased counter and we have number not only in label,but in item.
\tl_if_empty:NTF ##1 {\use:c { orig@#1 }##1}{\tagstructbegin{tag=Lbl}
\tagmcbegin{tag=Lbl}
\use:c { orig@#1 }##1
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}
}
}
}

% The declaration is global. The integer is initially equal to 0 (see
% interface3.pdf).
\int_new:N \g__aleksandr_list_level_int

\cs_new_eq:NN \__aleksandr_orig_start_list:nn \list
\cs_new_eq:NN \__aleksandr_orig_end_list: \endlist
\cs_new_eq:NN \__aleksandr_orig_start_trivlist:nn \trivlist
\cs_new_eq:NN \__aleksandr_orig_end_trivlist: \endtrivlist

\cs_new_eq:NN \__aleksandr_orig_item: \item
% Simple macro to reduce redundancy and the length of some lines. It expands
% to the list boolean variable name for the current level **without its
% backslash**.
\cs_new:Npn \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name:
  {
    g__aleksandr_first_item_ \int_use:N \g__aleksandr_list_level_int _bool
  }

\renewcommand \list
  {
    \int_compare:nNnF { \g__aleksandr_list_level_int } = { 0 }
      {
        % We need check, if we have items in previous level,and if yes, close mc
        % and struct before starting of the list.
        \bool_if:cT { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
          {
            \tagmcend \tagstructend
            %We close previous LI and LBody
            \tagstructend \tagstructend
            \bool_gset_false:c { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
          }

        \tagstructbegin { tag=LI }
        \tagstructbegin { tag=LBody }
      }

    \int_gincr:N \g__aleksandr_list_level_int
    \bool_if_exist:cF { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
      { \bool_new:c { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: } }

    \tagstructbegin { tag=L }
    \__aleksandr_orig_start_list:nn
  }

\renewcommand \endlist
  {
    \bool_if:cTF { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
      {
        \tagmcend
        \tagstructend
        \tagstructend
        \tagstructend
        \bool_gset_false:c { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
      }
      {
        % If we haven't items, but we have level more then one, we have sublist
        % before, so we should close LI and LBody.
        \int_compare:nNnF { \g__aleksandr_list_level_int - 1 } = { 0 }
          { \tagstructend \tagstructend }
      }
    \int_gdecr:N \g__aleksandr_list_level_int
    \__aleksandr_orig_end_list:
    \tagstructend
  }

  \renewcommand \trivlist
  {
    \int_compare:nNnF { \g__aleksandr_list_level_int } = { 0 }
      {
        % We need check, if we have items in previous level,and if yes, close mc
        % and struct before starting of the list.
        \bool_if:cT { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
          {
            \tagmcend \tagstructend
            %We close previous LI and LBody
            \tagstructend \tagstructend
            \bool_gset_false:c { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
          }

        \tagstructbegin { tag=LI }
        \tagstructbegin { tag=LBody }
      }

    \int_gincr:N \g__aleksandr_list_level_int
    \bool_if_exist:cF { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
      { \bool_new:c { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: } }

    \tagstructbegin { tag=L }
    \__aleksandr_orig_start_trivlist:nn
  \message{start~of~trivlist~\int_use:c{g__aleksandr_list_level_int}}
  }

\renewcommand \endtrivlist
  {
    \bool_if:cTF { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
      {
        \tagmcend
        \tagstructend
        \tagstructend
        \tagstructend
        \bool_gset_false:c { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
      }
      {
        % If we haven't items, but we have level more then one, we have sublist
        % before, so we should close LI and LBody.
        \int_compare:nNnF { \g__aleksandr_list_level_int - 1 } = { 0 }
          { \tagstructend \tagstructend }
      }
    \int_gdecr:N \g__aleksandr_list_level_int
    \__aleksandr_orig_end_trivlist:
    \tagstructend
  \message{end~of~trivlist~\int_use:c{g__aleksandr_list_level_int}}
  }
\renewcommand \item {
    \bool_if:cTF { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
      {
        \iow_term:n { True~value }
        % We have an item before, so we must close the last item, LBody and LI.
        \tagmcend \tagstructend \tagstructend \tagstructend
      }
      {
        \iow_term:n { False~value }
        % This code is only executed once.
        \bool_gset_true:c { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }
      }
\__aleksandr_orig_item:
    \tagstructbegin {tag=LBody}
    \tagstructbegin {tag=P}
    \tagmcbegin {tag=P}
}
%why for itemize and enumerate \endlist is not calls? We should replace \endenumerate and \enditemize commands on \endlist command,to fix it.
\let\endenumerate=\endlist
\let\enditemize=\endlist
\ExplSyntaxOff
\author{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\date{\today}
\title{\thanks{Sasha Kozlovskiy} test document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
%now it not works,because we not redefine center environment yet

\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\maketitle{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\item new test
\end{enumerate}
\everypar{\message{new~paragraph}}
Test

New test
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a `\bool_new:c { g__first_item_0_bool }` missing for the 0 level (\maketitle contains a center enviroment, and this is a list too.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer So,you mean,that for center it's not calls \list command,but calls only \item command,so i must check,if i inside center environment? But why when i have value 0 i have this error? Or,probably,i not understood you correct?

Comment: center uses trivlist, not list.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Ok,i understood,that \list command  not calls,so i should check,if i inside \center environment,but I not understood,why for 0 value i get an error,connected with number,but,for example,not error \undefined control sequence,because if i haven't \list command,i haven't this boolean variable.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy You only declare the boolean in `\list` (using `bool_new:c { \__aleksandr_list_level_bool_name: }`), and you do  this *after* doing `\int_gincr:N \g__aleksandr_list_level_int`. Therefore, you start declaring the boolean for level 1; for level 0, it is not declared. However, `\maketitle` uses `center` which is based on a `trivlist` environment, which does not call `\list` but does call `\item`. When your redefined `\item` is called by `\maketitle`, it performs the `\bool_if:cTF ...` test on the level-0 boolean which you have not declared, hence the error.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Unrelated to the error: in order to respect the naming conventions (namespaces), `g__first_item_` should be replaced with `g__aleksandr_first_item_` (I'm probably guilty of forgetting to do it last time).

Comment: `\bool_if:cT { some_unknown_bool } {a}` gives a missing number error, due to the way booleans are implemented.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Very strange,that we haven't this in expl3 interface documentation. according to the documentation we have:
> \bool_if_p:N hbooleani \bool_if:NTF hbooleani {htrue codei}{hfalse codei} 
Tests the current truth of hbooleani, and continues expansion based on this result.

Comment: sure that documents how defined bools work. But you have an undefined boolean.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Ok,but why i haven't undefined controle sequence error instead? Because number error misleaded to me and i want to know,how avoid this situation in future,i.e how to know,that in some moment missing number means,that variable undefined?

Comment: because with the c-type you are basically using `\csname something\endsname` and this doesn't give an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Ok,i want to clarify terminology. What is c-type? May be it controle sequence type? Also i want to understood,in what cases i will have number error,instead of undefined control sequence error,when my variable or function is undefined?

Comment: If you do `\bool_if:NT \l_unknown_bool` you an undefined control sequence error, if you do `\bool_if:cT {l_unknown_bool}` you get a different error.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy LaTeX (including `expl3`) error messages are often difficult to understand if you take them by the letter. They make sense when you analyse the cause of the error at the TeX level, but doing so is not always easy. In this case, `expl3` booleans are implemented are `\chardef` tokens: `\tex_chardef:D \c_true_bool = 1 ~`and `\tex_chardef:D \c_false_bool = 0 ~`. This means that `expl3` boolean variables are 〈number〉s from TeX's point of view. So, you have a test that tries to evaluate a boolean that hasn't been defined. TeX looks for a 〈number〉, doesn't find any, ...

Comment: ... therefore it reports. Since such low-level analysis is often too difficult or time consuming, what I'd suggest when you have a bug like this is to print the contents of relevant variables up to the point where you have the problem. At some point, you'll probably notice that one of the variables isn't as you expected. Then you should investigate why and finally come to a solution. Another approach that can help is to use the good old `\tracingmacros=1`, `tracingcommands=2` (or `1`) and `tracingonline=1`. They work in `expl3` too!

Comment: @frougon Ok,and how to print value of boolean variable correct,when it use constructions,such as \int_eval or int_use. Also i not understood,where and how to use,for example,\tracingonline=1 or \tracingmacros=1 or \tracingcommands=1 or 2. Also i want to understood,why for bool_if:ctf i have number error,and for bool_if:Ntf i have undefined control sequence error? Also i want to kno,where i can find sources of expl3 modules,such as bool etc. Before i considered,that expl3 it improved approach,but now after your comment,i understood,that expl3 works as a usual latex2,but only have other syntaks.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Many questions... IMHO, you should read the TeXbook. It will explain the `\tracing*` commands and many things that would help you. These commands can go basically anywhere where you can use `\def` or `\newcommand` (i.e., perform assignments). The `expl3` sources can be found in the [official latex3 repository](https://github.com/latex3/latex3) (see `l3kernel` directory). A PDF rendering of the `expl3` source code can be obtained with command `l3build doc` run from the `l3kernel/doc` folder (this creates a large `source3.pdf` file).

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy As for the other question, Ulrike already answered... `\bool_if:cTF` creates a control sequence token from the first argument with `\csname#1\endcsname`. When the result hasn't already been defined, this defines it as equivalent to `\relax`. Then `\bool_if:NTF` is called with the new control sequence token as its first argument. As I explained, TeX expects a 〈number〉, but as I just said, the new control sequence token is equivalent to `\relax`. So, TeX finds nothing but `\relax` while trying to read a 〈number〉: this generates the `Missing number, treated as zero.` error.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy On the other hand, with `\bool:NTF`, TeX will directly try to read a 〈number〉 from the first argument, without using `\csname` since it is a `N`-type argument, not `c`. When the control sequence (here, supposedly a bool) hasn't been defined, this generates an `Undefined control sequence` error, as usual. In the case of the `c` argument type, it is the `\csname` that defines the control sequence token (as `\relax`), and *that* results in a different error. `expl3` offers significant improvements over  LaTeX2e for serious programming in my opinion, ...

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy but both are very difficult (IMHO, a waste of time) without having first studied TeX. Hence my suggestion to read the TeXbook.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I noticed,that i still get an error for trivlist. According to my debug it's happends,because command \trivlist calls once,and command \endtrivlist calls twice. I not understand,why this happends. I will edit now my question to show problem.